# How to write if-then statement as a logical statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

I Java it's possible to represent IF-THEN statement in the following form:

```
a = (x==10) ? true : false;
```

that is equivalent to

```
if (x==10)
  a=true;
else
  a=false;
```

Is it possible to do the same thing in Python?

Comment: You could just do `a = (x == 10)` because the comparison *already produces a boolean*. The term you were looking for is *conditional expression*, which is a *ternary operator* (as opposed to binary operators like `+` or `==`, or unary operators like `-` or `not`)

Comment: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = True if x == 10 else False
```

or simply

```
a = x == 10
```

Comment: I only saw the `a = x == 10` part. You may want to use `True` and `False` instead of the javascript spellings.

Comment: What if I have 0 and 1 instead of False and True?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos: then you use `1 if x == 10 else 0`. Is that so hard to deduce? Or if you want to go obtuse: `int(x == 10)`, since Python booleans are subclasses of `int` and have the values `0` and `1`.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos then you can do `a = 1 if x == 10 else 0`